# Android Studio - Download images online

Tags: java, android, image, android-studio

In my app I want ot be able to load alot of images from a site (ddragon).
The problem is that every time I want to load an image it takes alot of time and power from the device, saving these photos will take alot of place and that is also a problem.

I would like to know what is the best way to handle alot of images (500+) in big sizes ( 200 ~ 300 dp for height and width), Thank you!

( Right now I am using Universal Image Loader )

```
   imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
   imageLoader.displayImage(q.getImageURL(), questionImage, null, new ImageLoadingListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {
            loadingView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) {
            finish();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed loading the image...\nID: " + q.getID(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
            loadingView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            myCountDownTimer.start();
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadingCancelled(String imageUri, View view) {
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend a third party library instead of reinventing the wheel. Square has a library called [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) that's quite popular.

You can do things like:

```
Picasso.with(context)
.load(url)
.resize(50, 50)
.centerCrop()
.into(imageView)
```

[Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) is also a popular one.

Comment: There's also a caching option for picasso that'll make it less intensive for repeated calls on those large images.

Answer (score 0):

***MainActivity.java***

```
import java.io.InputStream;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    // Set your Image URL into a string
    String URL = "Image URL for example http://www.google.com";
    ImageView image;
    Button button;
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Get the layout from image.xml
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Locate the ImageView in activity_main.xml
        image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);

        // Locate the Button in activity_main.xml
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        // Capture button click
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                // Execute DownloadImage AsyncTask
                new DownloadImage().execute(URL);
            }
        });
    }

    // DownloadImage AsyncTask
    private class DownloadImage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Create a progressdialog
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            // Set progressdialog title
            mProgressDialog.setTitle("Download Image Tutorial");
            // Set progressdialog message
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            // Show progressdialog
            mProgressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... URL) {

            String imageURL = URL[0];

            Bitmap bitmap = null;
            try {
                // Download Image from URL
                InputStream input = new java.net.URL(imageURL).openStream();
                // Decode Bitmap
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return bitmap;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
            // Set the bitmap into ImageView
            image.setImageBitmap(result);
            // Close progressdialog
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

***Activity_main.xml***

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" >
    </ImageView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/image"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and internet permission in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" >
```

[source](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-download-image-from-url/)